# Numpy matrix row comparison

Tags: python, performance, numpy, matrix, comparison

The question is more focused on performance of calculation.

I have 2 matrix with the same number of columns and different number of rows. One matrix is the 'pattern' whose rows have to be compared separately with the other matrix rows (all rows), then to be able to extract statistical values of mean equal to pattern, std,...
So, I have the following matrix and the computation is the following one:

```
numCols = 10
pattern = np.random.randint(0,2,size=(7,numCols))
matrix = np.random.randint(0,2,size=(5,numCols))

comp_mean = np.zeros(pattern.shape[0])
for i in range(pattern.shape[0]):
    comp_mean[i] = np.mean(np.sum(pattern[i,:] == matrix, axis=1))

print comp_mean # Output example: [ 1.6  1.   1.6  2.2  2.   2.   1.6]
```

This is clear. The problem is that the number of matrix rows of both is much bigger (~1.000.000). So this code goes very slow. I tryed to implement numpy syntaxis as sometimes it surprises me improving the calculation time. So I did the following code (it could be strange, but it works!):

```
comp_mean = np.mean( np.sum( (pattern[np.repeat(np.arange(pattern.shape[0]), matrix.shape[0])].ravel() == np.tile(matrix.ravel(),pattern.shape[0])).reshape(pattern.shape[0],matrix.shape[0],matrix.shape[1]), axis=2 ),axis=1)
print comp_mean
```

However, this code is slower than the previous one where the 'for' bucle is used. So I would like to know if there is any possibility to speed up the calculation.

**EDIT**

I have checked the runtime of the different approaches for the real matrix and the result is the following:

- Me - Approach 1:  **18.04** seconds
- Me - Approach 2:  **303.10** seconds
- Divakar - Approach 1:  **18.79** seconds
- Divakar - Approach 2:  **65.11** seconds
- Divakar - Approach 3.1:  **137.78** seconds
- Divakar - Approach 3.2:  **59.59** seconds
- Divakar - Approach 4:  **6.06** seconds

**EDIT(2)**

Previous runs where performed in a laptop. I have run the code on a desktop. I have avoided the worst results, and the new runtimes are now different:

- Me - Approach 1:  **6.25** seconds
- Divakar - Approach 1:  **4.01** seconds
- Divakar - Approach 2:  **3.66** seconds
- Divakar - Approach 4:  **3.12** seconds

Comment: How big is `pattern`?

Comment: @Divakar, for the runtime test exposed, pattern number rows 100.000 and matrix 1.000 rows.

Comment: Check out the added approach #4?

Comment: @Divakar your last approach has the best performance. Do you think that it is still possible to go further, or as you said, as matrix is too big is better to stick to a for-loop? I will try the same code in a machine with big memory to check if that could be a bottle neck on computation

Comment: Would be definitely interesting to see how it performs on a high end machine. With vectorized codes and huge datasizes, there's always this tussle, specially when the operation is a reduction. Made a slight edit to approach #4, though won't make a huge impact though I suspect.

Comment: No difference with that update on approach 4. I have checked that my approach2 and your approach 3 I cannot run them because I run out of memory although I have 24 GB ...

Comment: Made one more slight edit to appr #4, must be a tiny bit faster now. But, I wasn't expecting appr#4 to be slower than your appro #1, that's sort of a surprising result for me.

Comment: @Divakar, now with that last update it performs better. On laptop, from 8.34 to 6.06. And on desktop, from 8.48 to 3.12!!!

Comment: That's lovely! Thanks for getting all those runtimes!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Few approaches with [`broadcasting`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) could be suggested here.

**Approach #1**

```
out = np.mean(np.sum(pattern[:,None,:] == matrix[None,:,:],2),1)
```

**Approach #2**

```
mrows = matrix.shape[0]
prows = pattern.shape[0]
out = (pattern[:,None,:] == matrix[None,:,:]).reshape(prows,-1).sum(1)/mrows
```

**Approach #3**

```
mrows = matrix.shape[0]
prows = pattern.shape[0]
out = np.einsum('ijk->i',(pattern[:,None,:] == matrix[None,:,:]).astype(int))/mrows
# OR out = np.einsum('ijk->i',(pattern[:,None,:] == matrix[None,:,:])+0)/mrows
```

---

**Approach #4**

If the number of rows in `matrix` is a huge number, it could be better to stick to a for-loop to avoid the huge memory requirements for such a case, that might also lead to slow runtimes. Instead, we could do some optimizations within each loop iteration. Here's one such possible optimization shown -

```
mrows = matrix.shape[0]
comp_mean = np.zeros(pattern.shape[0])
for i in range(pattern.shape[0]):
    comp_mean[i] = (pattern[i,:] == matrix).sum()
comp_mean = comp_mean/mrows
```

Comment: Approach #4 is very surprising... and `np.einsum`... interesting. +1.

Comment: @rayryeng Just the memory requirements for such huge reduction operation is the biggest reason with `matrix` being extremely bigger than `pattern` might be the reason here.

Comment: @rayryeng, I agree with you that `np.einsum` is interesting. I didn't even know that function :S

Comment: @isal I found this page that goes into more detail: http://ajcr.github.io/Basic-guide-to-einsum/ - The `numpy` documentation is woefully inaccurate.

Answer (score 0):

could you have a try at this:

```
import scipy.ndimage.measurements

comp_mean = np.zeros(pattern.shape[0])
for i in range(pattern.shape[0]):
    m = scipy.ndimage.measurements.histogram(matrix,0,1,2,pattern[i],[0,1])
    comp_mean[i] = m[0][0]+m[1][1]
comp_mean /= matrix.shape[0]
```

Regards.

Comment: the problem with this code is that pattern rows can contain only zeros or ones which makes m[0][0] or m[1][1] not to exist returning a TypeError. I have tried changing your line with the following `comp_mean[i] = int(0 if np.size(m[0]) == 1 else m[0][0]) + int(0 if np.size(m[1]) == 1 else m[1][1])` which may not be the most optimized line, because the runtime is **250.35** seconds. If you find another better way to do it, let me know to check runtime.

Comment: 3 labels. I modified your code, but as I explained, the problem comes when one of the labels is not in the pattern row that you compare on the loop, because m[n][n] does not exist giving a TypeError and stopping execution.

Comment: @isai Try something like   m = scipy.ndimage.measurements.histogram(matrix,0,2,3,pattern[i],[0,1,2]) and then m[0][0]+m[1][1]+m[2][2]  Regards.

Comment: That is what I tried when I refer that I modified your code. However, as I said, when you have a row from pattern that has no values of one label (let's say all zeros on a row), m[1][1] does not exist. It is empty. So this gives a TypeError stopping the execution. Try with the following matrix to understand what I mean: `pattern = np.array([[1,1,1,1,1,1,1],[1,1,0,0,1,1,0],[0,1,1,1,1,0,1]])
matrix = np.array([[0,1,1,0,0,0,0],[0,1,0,0,1,1,0]])`

Comment: OK, I understand; the idea is probably not very good. I suggested it because scipy.ndimage is very quick for some computations related to "labels" on arrays, but your own problem seems to be a little different.

Comment: I appreciate your try anyway. It could be a good solution in another a pattern which has all types of labels at each row.